# Node js npm install -g not working in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js

Hi I am getting "You don't have permission denied for write" ?

sudo npm install

sudo is use to add super user privileged.

Comment: You are not using "sudo"

Try:
    sudo npm install
    or
   sudo npm install -g

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo npm install` or `sudo npm install -g`, if it prompts you for a username or password use the one for your computer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo npm install
or

sudo npm install -g
```

Answer (score 0):

**To install npm packages globally without sudo** (recommended)
Follow the instructions given in the following links

- [Solution by Sindre sorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)
- [npm official docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)